# How to configure my EC2 instance in Route 53

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, routes

I have deployed my node application in aws ec2 When I hit the ip with my port it is working and when I thought of using the same ip for Route 53 alias IPv4 it is just location. 
The issue is If I use the port 8080 with ip it is working without port number it is not working ! What Should I do !
Eg. 1222.12.12.22:8080 working 
1222.12.12.22 not working just loading

Answer (score 2):

Port 8080 is a non-standard web server port. Web browsers will default to using port 80 for HTTP and port 443 for HTTPS. DNS servers do not operate at the port level. DNS servers just map domain names to IP addresses. Port numbers are not part of the process.

There is nothing wrong. You just need to specify the port number when using non-standard ports.